# Dynamically creating Angular components

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have some HTML content that I'm injecting dynamically into my page (the content is from an external source). That content has certain placeholders (elements) that need to be replaced with Angular components and wired into my application. Is this possible with AngularJS?

Comment: This might help you: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html

Comment: yes it is possible. you need to compile your html string using $compile service and then inject the string into your hmml template. 
i have achieved it for the angular directives.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible in both angularjs and angular2

In angularjs you will create a directive and in angular2 you will create a component.

In angularjs you can also create a component now.